# Href link to send me to the image url for all the images displayed using a loop

Tags: php, html

My question is: I have made a webpage which displays some images taken from the image folder using a loop. I want to be able to click on an image and open that specific image.

```
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $dirname = "uploads/";
    $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
    $linkk = "/uploads/1.jpg";

    foreach($images as $image) {
echo '  <div class="col-xs-3 ">
    <a href=  ".$linkk"  class="thumbnail">
      <img src="'.$image.' " >
    </a> 
  </div>
';
$count++;

}
?>
```

The problem is the images are displayed on the screen fine, but I can not seem to click an image and open it in another value.
My images are in uploads/ Folder. I cant get the href to dynamically send me to the specific image url.

Comment: `".$linkk"` should be `"' . $image . '"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<img src =` should link to the same thing as your `<a href =`.

Like this

```
<a href=  "'.$image.' "  class="thumbnail">
      <img src="'.$image.' " ></a>
```

Comment: THANKYOU SBOWDE4 and kommrad! i cant believe i missed such a small detail! it works great now !

Comment: @Absar A. Khan Glad I could help, if it isn't two much trouble. Please accept this answer as correct.

Comment: its fine! Thank you!

Comment: can i bother you with another question, i need to make a search option that searches through my /uploads/ directory and shows images with the keyword in their name.can u help me with the php part , i have already made the search bar ,ty!

Comment: I actually do not know a lot about to php, I have made exactly one search engine before. That was along time ago. Basically what I did was, I created a database, it really only needs two fields. You need to insert the name of the image into one field, and the url or path into the other. Search the database for your keyword and select the contents of the record it matches (url and name). Then link to the image like you did in your loop with the data you pulled

Comment: that is just one way to do it, I am sure there are more. This video can explain it more to you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gf32KXTP0C4